# Are files untouched for 5 years susceptible to corruption?

Tags: hard-drive, backup

I have been allowing Robocopy to mirror the contents of my home computer disk to an external flash drive for almost 5 years now. This has been my backup strategy.

I realize that many files in some directories have not been touched (used, read, opened) by me during this time. Is Robocopy doing some kind of verification for me or are these files slowly rotting?

In general, how do I maintain files in the long term? Any recommendations?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is Robocopy doing some kind of verification for me

No.  Not a feature of Robocopy.

> are these files slowly rotting

You don't know unless you are doing the following:

- Maintaining a second copy and periodically comparing each file, and restoring corrupt files.
- Storing files with error recovery information (look into PAR2 files for an example)

> In general, how do I maintain files in the long term?

Refresh to new medium every X years.  5 or 6 is good number here.

Extremely important text documents should be printed where practical.  It's possible to seal paper from the elements using lamination or other techniques and guarantee availability for decades.

Tape is designed for long-term storage and is probably the best if you want to keep data for 5+ years.  Your main challenges will be finding a place to store it that's climate controlled and keeping a couple working drives in the event they don't make them any more.

Comment: Thank you. You wrote, "Maintaining a second copy and periodically comparing each file" I let Robocopy go on the whole drive. So, unless I see a file has been changed in the log output, I can assume the source files have not been degraded?

Answer (score 2):

All drives of all kinds wear out. There is no such thing as a very long term permanent drive. Five years plus or minus is a reasonable limit. Commercial SSD drives now have a longer life expectancy than hard drives.

I keep multiple copies of important documents on multiple computers and drives. I renew computers every five or six years. This helps to ensure that important documents are safe. Individual documents are not usually subject to small scale corruption but whole drives can become defective.

I have not lost important documents.

Comment: As stated, make *multiple copies* in *multiple locations* for important files. Store redundant copies in the cloud and/or on different devices. You might zip files once a year to keep in a long-term storage location.

Comment: I understand that the act of copying an untouched file (5+ yrs or so) onto a secondary drive will initiate some kind of verification/validation to ensure its integrity on the new drive. And mirroring does this, too (as two copies of a file will show up as different/changed if one is rotting) but that I should really be worrying about the whole drive failing instead of worrying on a per file basis?

Comment: So long as you copy to more than one location / drive you have much less to worry about a whole drive failing. I use Sync Back Pro to manage backups and incremental copies and I do not find files changed by degradation (I have not seen this). I do manage to have orphan files (operator error) and I sync frequently enough (at least daily) that I can easily correct orphans

Answer (score 1):

Yes, bit rot does occur slowly over time.

> how do I maintain files in the long term? Any recommendations?

This depends on the level of dependability and complexity you can handle.

1. Multiple copies
2. A cloud like google drive, crashplan, or etc
3. RAID 1 (mirroring) can be done software or hardware
4. RAID 5/6 can handle 1/2 bad drives.
5. WinRAR has a parity option which, if enabled, can repair itself.  This requires you use it compress all your files into a single RAR file.  A 1% parity level should be enough to repair any normally occurring corruption.  However, you still need 2 copies in case the whole drive fails.
6. Given the cost and size of thumb drives moving the data each year to a new thumb drive and keeping last 2 years external drives is probably a good choice.
   Running a separate program to verify the contents copied correctly.  A program which generates sha256 or similar could be used.